# WSH scripts unit testing framework

Tags: unit-testing, vbscript, wsh

I'm looking for a unit testing framework for WSH scripts (vbs/wsf, not VB6, VBA).

I can't find anything except this project (looks good, but last activity was recorder around 2 years ago, haven't tested it yet):

http://code.google.com/p/vbslib/

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There also is [ScriptUnit](http://www.xt1.org/scriptunit) and if you just google for "vbscript unittest" you find [an ancient posting of mine](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/unit-testing-for-vbscript-m3487.aspx) (not very successful). I'm still interested in the topic and would like to cooperate in a way suitable for you.

Comment: Actually I did find that post, but missed X1 URL (blindness...). Thanks!

Comment: Few questions:
1. How did you manage to execute asserts? I have WSH version 5.8 and I'm getting "Class not registerd" error.
2. How did you include vbs files being tested into test files? (ReadAll, Execute?)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you are refering to. My unit test 'system' is a bit like the Perl approach (no classes (necessary)), you just call a compare for suitable values; the module 'system' is implemented by ReadAll and ExecuteGlobal; it needs a preprocessing step to get line numbers and syntactic sugar.

Comment: @AmonPL - In your Test .vbs files, you can 'include' functions and subs from another .vbs file, using ExecuteGlobal.

Comment: In the end I decided to migrate scripts to python (and use Jenkins to test them) but Ekkehard.Horner answer is good, as I'm accepting it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I just pushed a GitHub repo that includes an ultra-lightweight VBScript-based unit testing framework. Right now it only has AssertEqual and AssertErrorRaised, but it would be super easy to add more, if that's even necessary: https://github.com/koswald/VBScript

Here is a snippet from a [spec file](https://github.com/koswald/VBScript/blob/master/spec/VBSValidator.spec.vbs)

```
With CreateObject("includer")
    Execute(.read("VBSValidator"))
    Execute(.read("TestingFramework"))
End With

Dim val : Set val = New VBSValidator 'Class Under Test

With New TestingFramework

    .describe "VBSValidator class"

    .it "should return True when IsBoolean is given a True"

        .AssertEqual val.IsBoolean(True), True

End With
```

And here is a sample [test launcher](https://github.com/koswald/VBScript/blob/master/examples/TestLauncher.vbs)

```
Main
Sub Main
    With CreateObject("includer")
        ExecuteGlobal(.read("VBSTestRunner"))
    End With
    Dim testRunner : Set testRunner = New VBSTestRunner
    With WScript.Arguments
        If .Count Then

            'if it is desired to run just a single test file, pass it in on the 
            'command line, using a relative path, relative to the spec folder

            testRunner.SetSpecFile .item(0)
        End If
    End With

    'specify the folder containing the tests; path is relative to this script

    testRunner.SetSpecFolder "../spec"

    'run the tests

    testRunner.Run
End Sub
```

Comment: Karl, thx. Could you please cut and paste a useful snippet here so this isn't [Your answer is in another castle: When is an answer not an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370)

Comment: Thanks for your comment Drew. I made the changes accordingly, I hope.

Comment: Thx for sharing Karl :p