# Test Harness for VBScript

Tags: unit-testing, vbscript

I have a number of legacy VBScript files that I want to bring under test harness, they mostly deal with lower level system functions (deleting old cache data etc.). I've looked into using http://www.xt1.org/scriptunit, but I'm very new to Visual Basic (most of my testing experience lies in shunit for bash scripting and mocha for Ruby), and was a little disappointed that Script Unit hasn't been worked on for over 7 years and there doesn't seem to be much/any community support for it.

We're also looking for open-source/free solutions, though I know this is more difficult to find in this situation.

Any suggestions of tools/technologies for VBScript test harnessing would be most welcome.

Comment: cf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595067/wsh-scripts-unit-testing-framework

Answer (score 0):

It might be a stretch, though, I hear you can test VBScript in VisualStudio's Team System testing tools:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182622.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vststest/thread/586564cc-6ef3-4ba4-b791-77b26187846b/

Since you are asking for "suggestions of tools/technologies for VBScript test harnessing", my suggestion is **VBScript in VisualStudio's Team System testing tools with generic tests**.

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer, because it consists of nothing but links offsite and a "I hear you can", which really doesn't answer the question. You should either rephrase it and add more meaningful content or delete it. (You don't have sufficient rep yet to make it a comment instead.) Answers should do just that - provide an actual answer to the question asked, with sufficient details to help a future reader. If the links change (which happens even at MSDN), your post loses all meaning.